# Extract facial landmarks point from UIImage using open cv in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition

I want to extract the facial landmarks point from image using open cv , I don't know how to extract all facial points have anyone done this in iOS Xcode using open cv ?

Comment: Not sure about iOS, but for C++ you can use https://github.com/delphifirst/FaceX or Dlib's: http://blog.dlib.net/2014/08/real-time-face-pose-estimation.html. DLIB uses only header files therefore integration is much simpler.